# How to select specific fields from nested relations in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following query in Eloquent:

```
 public function firstSubsectionIdsOnly()
    {
        return $this->model->with(['sections' => function ($q) {
            $q->with(['subsections' => function ($q2) {
                $q2->first();

            }
            ])->first();
        }])->whereHas('sections.subsections')->first();
    }
```

This returns something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Training exercise",
    "entry": "<p>sss</p>",
    "created_at": "2018-04-20 09:38:36",
    "updated_at": "2018-04-20 10:08:27",
    "sections": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Section 1 Training",
            "parent": null,
            "position": 1,
            "created_at": "2018-05-04 09:37:23",
            "updated_at": "2018-05-04 09:37:23",
            "pivot": {
                "training_exercise_id": 1,
                "section_id": 1
            },
            "subsections": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Subsection 1 training",
                    "parent": 1,
                    "created_at": "2018-05-04 09:54:09",
                    "updated_at": "2018-05-04 09:54:09"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like for it to only select the id fields for each relation so it should return something like this:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Training exercise",
        "entry": "<p>sss</p>",
        "created_at": "2018-04-20 09:38:36",
        "updated_at": "2018-04-20 10:08:27",
        "sections": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "subsections": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I have tried adding `$q->select('id');` to the `subsections` nested closure but that returns an empty `subsections` array.

Any idea on how I can achieve this? I am using Laravel 5.6

Comment: "I have tried adding `$q->select('id');` to the nested closure". Which nested closure? You have two using the same parameter. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: I have tried it in the `subsections` closure and also changed the parameter name to `$q2`. Still returns an empty array for `subsections`

Comment: @Loek Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated before, you need to include the foreign key in the values you select. Let's say we have two models. `Parent` and `Child`. This is the bare minimum you have to select.

```
App\Parent::select('id')->with(['children' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'parent_id');
}])->get();
```

It nets you something like

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
    all: [
        App\Parent {
            id: 1,
            children: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
                all: [
                    App\Child {
                        id: 109,
                        parent_id: 1,
                    },
                    App\Child {
                        id: 153,
                        parent_id: 1,
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

If you're trying to go for the inverse, you still need the foreign key, like so

```
App\Child::select('id', 'parent_id')->with('parent' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('id');
}])->get();
```

This nets you

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
    all: [
        App\Child {
            id: 1,
            parent_id: 58,
            parent: App\Parent {
                id: 58,
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

I'm using `select()` instead of `get()` for legibility on the queries but you **must** use `select()` for the subqueries.

If you use `with('relation') => function ($query) { $query->get(['id']); }` you'll get the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the foreign key columns. For the `subsections` relationship:

```
$q2->select('id', 'parent');
```

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?